# i want to change my wordpress pod domain name

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-app-service-plans

I hope you all are doing great today ,

here is my situation :

i have 2 wordpress websites (identical )

--1st one is an App Service wordpress in azure with a domain name eg:https://wordpress.azurewebsites.net

--the 2nd one is in aks cluster as a pod with a load balancer that expose it to the internet with a public ip

what i want to do :

i want to take the domain name from the app service and give it to the aks pod

what did i do :

i changed from the dashboard the domain name and changed the load balancer public ip adress
and it didn't work now i can't access the dashboard from the load balancer ip adress either

im new in kubernetes i hope someone can guide me to the right direction on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are missing an ingress controller. You could for example install ingress-nginx and expose the ingress with this service config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 53.1.1.1
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
    appProtocol: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

You can now create a service for your app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app_service
  namespace: app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: service
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: yoour_app
```

Then you can expose yoour app with an ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app_ingress
  namespace: app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - wordpress.azurewebsites.net
  rules:
    - host: wordpress.azurewebsites.net
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app_service
                port:
                  number: 80
```